# Enable to connect through 465 port

Tags: symfony

I am trying to send an email. Everything works fine on localhost but not on production:

> Connection could not be established with host
> "ssl://smtp.gmail.com:465": stream_socket_client(): Unable to connect
> to ssl://smtp.gmail.com:465 (Network is unreachable)

```
$dsn = Transport::fromDsn('gmail+smtp://mygmail@gmail.com:myapppassword@default');
$mailer = new Mailer($dsn);
$mailer->send($email);
```

From the documentation about emails, I saw that the problem might be the missing `verify_peer` parameter in the end. So I tried with both 0 and 1 like:

```
$dsn = Transport::fromDsn('gmail+smtp://mygmail@gmail.com:myapppassword@default?verify_peer=0');
```

and

```
 $dsn = Transport::fromDsn('gmail+smtp://mygmail@gmail.com:myapppassword@default?verify_peer=1');
```

Don't see where can I pass the tls port actually.

Comment: Is the port open in your firewall? (Using ufw maybe). Is your site accessible via https and working?

Comment: Yes, it is accessible via https.  `Is the port open in your firewall` where can I check this in cpanel ?

Comment: @Bossman I general I don't understand how to pass the tls 587 dsn.  This nee d to be `tls://smtp.gmail.com:587` and not like currently - `ssl`.